# Hide price for specific categories on cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, content-management-system, cart

I am trying to hide the specific categories price from the products page + cart and I am using this code snippet which I have found elsewhere.

```
<?php 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', function( $price, $product ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return $price;
    // Hide for these category slugs / IDs
    $hide_for_categories = array( 'berkley','cotton-lite','kinna','linen','luster','nairobi','panama','plisse','prints','sequoia','shantung','brocade','boucle','dover','lite-out','lite-out-duplex','moire','sheerweave-blackout','sutton','texas-green','windsor','sheer','sheerweave-3-5-10','sheerweave-specialty');
    // Don't show price when its in one of the categories
    if ( has_term( $hide_for_categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $price; // Return original price
}, 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', '__return_false' );
 ?>
```

The problem that I am facing is that this code hides all the categories price from the cart.It's working perfect for product pages but not on the cart. Anyone can help me what to change in the code? I am newbie to WordPress coding.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, will hide the price and total on the cart page for each product that is in your category list.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'hide_woocommerce_cart_item_price', 10, 3);
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'hide_woocommerce_cart_item_price', 10, 3);

function hide_woocommerce_cart_item_price( $price,  $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']);
    $hide_for_categories = array( 'berkley','cotton-lite','kinna','linen','luster','nairobi','panama','plisse','prints','sequoia','shantung','brocade','boucle','dover','lite-out','lite-out-duplex','moire','sheerweave-blackout','sutton','texas-green','windsor','sheer','sheerweave-3-5-10','sheerweave-specialty');
    // Don't show price when its in one of the categories
    if ( has_term( $hide_for_categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $price; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, man. It helps exactly as I was looking for. One more thing, it still shows the price when I hover over the cart icon and a dropdown list of products appear with the price there although from the cart page it is hidden.

Comment: @AzeemAmin sounds like that's a theme dependent issue.  Please raise a new question and I will assist with it.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, I will let you know here when I will post that question because as I am new here that's why I can only post 1 question per day.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532567/how-to-hide-specific-product-categories-price-from-cart-icon-dropdown
Here is the link Andrew to my new question.