# How to hide specific product categories price from cart icon dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have some product categories which I don't to show the price to the user. Successfully hide the price from the product pages and also from the cart page but the price still showing in the cart icon when the user hovers over the icon and a dropdown list appear of the products that are in the cart.

Anyone know how to fix this? Any help will be appreciated.This is the code that I am using to hide the price for the specific category.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'hide_woocommerce_cart_item_price', 10, 3);
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'hide_woocommerce_cart_item_price', 10, 3);

function hide_woocommerce_cart_item_price( $price,  $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']);
    $hide_for_categories = array( 'berkley','cotton-lite','kinna','linen','luster','nairobi','panama','plisse','prints','sequoia','shantung','brocade','boucle','dover','lite-out','lite-out-duplex','moire','sheerweave-blackout','sutton','texas-green','windsor','sheer','sheerweave-3-5-10','sheerweave-specialty');
    // Don't show price when its in one of the categories
    if ( has_term( $hide_for_categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $price; 
}
```

Comment: What theme are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This should hide the subtotal in the cart hover but it's dependent on the theme you are using.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal', 'hide_woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal', 10, 4);

function hide_woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal( $sub_total, $product, $quantity, $cart ) {
    $hide_for_categories = array( 'berkley','cotton-lite','kinna','linen','luster','nairobi','panama','plisse','prints','sequoia','shantung','brocade','boucle','dover','lite-out','lite-out-duplex','moire','sheerweave-blackout','sutton','texas-green','windsor','sheer','sheerweave-3-5-10','sheerweave-specialty');
    // Don't show price when its in one of the categories
    if ( has_term( $hide_for_categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    return $sub_total;
}
```

Comment: Andrew, I am using Phoenix theme and on hover, it is only showing product price not sub-total and I only want to hide the price from the hover

Comment: @AzeemAmin try the code it might still work, sub-total is just what they call the price when multiplied by the quantity.  If not then I'll need to get a copy of the theme.

Comment: @AzeemAmin I'd need to see the source code of your theme. Upload it to dropbox so I can download it and take a look.